# How to call a method with a string

Tags: java, string, oop

I am trying to use a string to call a method?

Suppose I have a class called `Kyle` which has 3 methods:

```
public void Test();
public void Ronaldo();
public void MakeThis();
```

And I have a string with the name of the method which I need to call:

```
String text = "Test()";
```

Now I need to call the method whose name is inside of this string:

```
Kyle k = new Kyle();
```

`k.text;`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll need to use java `Reflection` to do this.

See: [Class.getMethod()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getMethod%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class...%29)

Using your specific example:

```
String text = "Test";
Kyle k = new Kyle();
Class clas = k.getClass();

// you'll need to handle exceptions from these methods, or throw them:
Method method = clas.getMethod(text, null);
method.invoke(k, null);
```

That's without the exception handling required for `getMethod()` and `Method.invoke()`, and only covers the case of calling methods that take no arguments.

See also:

- [Method doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html)
- [Class doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html)
- [This reflection article with examples](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/ALT/Reflection/)

Answer (score 3):

Reflection is an interesting feature in Java. It allows basic introspection. Here use `k.getClass().getMethod()`

eg

```
String text = "Test";
Kyle k = new Kyle();
Method testMethod = k.getClass().getMethod(text, new Class<?>[] { 
    /*List parameter classes here eg. String.class , Kyle.class or leave empty for none*/} 
Object returnedValue = testMethod.invoke(k, new Object[] { 
    /* Parameters go here or empty for none*/});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use something called [**Reflection**](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/ALT/Reflection/).

Comment: The problem with this answer is the link is dead

Answer (score 0):

Try reflection.

```
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
class Kyle {
    public void Test(){System.out.println("invoking Test()");}
    public void Ronaldo(){System.out.println("invoking Ronaldo()");}
    public void MakeThis(){System.out.println("invoking MakeThis()");}

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        Kyle k=new Kyle();
        String text = "Test";
        Class c=k.getClass();
        Method m=c.getDeclaredMethod(text);
        m.invoke(k);
    }
}
```

output

`invoking Test()`